# handle hundreds of documents as batch Autohotkey or Powershell

Tags: autohotkey

I have hundreds of documents sealed with Oracle IRM.
As we are using another Sealing Software in future I have to unseal the files.

The problem is that I have to handle each file manually.

I need to rightclick, click on Unseal and hit Enter to Save

Is there a way to do this automatically for all the files? All of them are in the same folder.

I have Autohotkey available but never done anything with it.
Powershell is always available.

Thanks

meostef

Comment: Does rightclick of more than one document show this menu item (Unseal)?

Comment: No that is the point. Unseal is only availble for one file at the time. Not for multiple files.

Comment: Does the program (or another one) have any menu item or a shortcut  that removes the seal of the document opened in that program?

Comment: How do you select the file? Can you use the arrow keys to select the next file? Is there a menu (other than right-click on the file) that you can use to unlock the selected file? In other words, see what you can do through the keyboard instead of the mouse. The mouse is difficult as the list will probably auto-scroll.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with Autohotkey.
Rightclick, move down 10 times, enter, enter

And then repeat for all

It worked.